# MariaDB - Want to change default value from "NULL" to an actual String

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to make a new column, whose type is an INT but default value is `NULL` but I want to change that default value to a string such as "No value" but it throws me this error: `ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'table_name'` when I run this command:

`ALTER TABLE my_table ADD column_1 INT DEFAULT 'No Value';`.

Can someone please guide me or if this is even possible or am I just wasting my time?

In the end result I want something like this:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+             
| column_1    | int          | YES  |     |No Value |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Where if I run a query, instead of NULL showing up, I would want it to show "No Value" instead.

Comment: You can't expect to store a character value in an integer column. Fix this in the presentation layer instead.

Comment: so you're saying to change the type to a varchar instead? But I need to be able to store integers. If however, no integers can be stored then instead of having NULL for that particular row I want to have my own custom message.

Comment: I say the opposite, keep integer data type. Store null. Let the presentation layer print "No value" when null is received.

Comment: Oh I see. Okay that makes a lot of sense. Do you have an example by which I could guide myself with? sqlfiddle?

Comment: store null and then `select coalesce(column_1,'No Value') from ...`.  Or just select null, and then in the client change it to No Value

Comment: thanks @ysth and jarlh for both of yours help. I've solved it and it's working now. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Used

```
select coalesce(column_1,'No Value') 
  from my_table
```

and it worked like a charm. Just replaced the `NULL` values in the table with my desired string.